# Problems Appending to array with 0's

Tags: swift

```
let tpmsvalue = Double("0")
let pressureKpa = Double(tpmsvalue!) * 1.572 * 2
dongleData.tpmsList?.append(pressureKpa)
```

when i am printing i will printing `nil` instead of 0.0. any help?

Comment: maybe tmpsList is nil

Comment: Add more code and clarifications what exactly do you need ?

Comment: What are you printing?

Comment: po dongleData.tpmsList

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `dongleData.tpmsList` is `nil` — because you have never set it to anything else. Saying `append` won't change that. You must set `dongleData.tpmsList` to an *actual array* at some point, or it will just stay `nil` forever. For instance, you could set it to `[]`, an empty array. Now you can append to that array.

Comment: var tpmsList: [Double] = [Double]() it worked thanks